# Rails: should 'double' user class (with polymorphic assoc) be created in model or controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, omniauth, registration

I have a user class with an inseparable polymorphic association (depending on a user type). Every time a new user is created the corresponding user type model must also be created. User can be created not only via regular registration but also using omniauth (facebook, google).
The question is: should I create user and user type in each action or add custom create function in user model, pass type of user and some parameters and create both user and user type there?

Here is create action from my registration controller:

```
def create

if params[:type] == 'employee'
  @user_type = Employee.new sign_up_params[:user_type_attributes]
elsif params[:type] == "customer"
  @user_type = Customer.new sign_up_params[:user_type_attributes]
elsif params[:type] == "owner"
  @user_type = Owner.new sign_up_params[:user_type_attributes]
else
  flash[:notice]="Invalid parameter"
  redirect_to :controller=>'welcome', :action=>'register_choice'
  return
end

build_resource(sign_up_params)

if resource.valid? && @user_type.valid?

  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    super do

      @user_type.save
      resource.user_type = @user_type

      if !@user_type.persisted? || !resource.persisted?
        clean_up_passwords resource
        set_minimum_password_length
        flash[:alert]="Error"
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
      end
    end
  end


else
  #TODO error messages
  clean_up_passwords resource
  set_minimum_password_length
  flash[:alert]="Error"
  respond_with resource
end  
end
```

Comment: did u use devise? ist devise registration controller ?

Comment: Yes, it's overwritten devise controller and it works. But I also want to create users in omniauth callbacks and I wonder whether I should just copy it or encapsulate it in some model action like createFrom(type,user_params,user_type_params).

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, certain things need to happen after a user is created.  The rails way would be to add an"after_create" callback in your user model that handles what you need once a user is created.  This will maintain conformity when adding to your app or collaborating with others.

Comment: Actually I want it to happen simultaneously, so that no user is saved without user_type saved (that is why I wrapped it in a transaction)